# How to Connect Firebase Auth Emulator With Python

Tags: python, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

i am new to python and trying to figure out how to connect my auth emulator with python project. Actually, i want to create the users on emulator but when i create a user it is created on my real time firebase project

- I have ini the firebase project in my python project
- I have exported the following environment variable
  ***export FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST="localhost:9099"*** from terminal and also set the **os.env** from my file but nothing worked for me
- I also used the method provided by pyrebase **create_user_with_email_and_password** for creating a user but this creates the user on firebase real project
  [The image of what i have done so far is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sD50.png)

If anyone knows the solution please let me know it will be very grateful for me!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen for guiding me next time i will take care of that !

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone else, this is how I managed to connect and use the auth emulator in python:

```
# Import auth from firebase admin
from firebase_admin import auth

# Set the auth emulator environment variable to the correct port, as shown when starting up the emulator.

if USE_EMULATOR == 'True':
  os.environ["FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST"] = "127.0.0.1:9099"


user = auth.create_user(email=email, password=password )
```